# variable div id MVC @<div id = "Activity @VARIABLENAME>

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'd like to know if it is possible to ID a < div> with a variable value.
I'm writing out an unknown number of "notes" using a hover function, therefore each  must be shown or hidden depending on the mouse position, and thus, each div ID must be unique, with the same class (please correct me if I'm wrong...)

Here's my code:

```
 @code
   For Each Activity In Model.Activities
     @<div id = "Activity @activity.ClgCode" class = "ActivityDetails">
     <br /> Activity @Activity.ClgCode:
      <b>
       @Activity.Notes
      </b>
    </div>
    Next
End Code
```

as you can see, I am trying to set up each < div> to use the class "ActivityDetails" but each ID should be unique, however I can't find any syntax anywhere for IDing < div>'s this way!
Thanks in advance for any help, and for taking time to read.
Cal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

As IDs in HTML can't have space. Use

```
 <div id ='@("Activity" + Activity.ClgCode)' class = "ActivityDetails">
```

### OR

```
 <div id ='@string.Format("Activity{0}", Activity.ClgCode)' class = "ActivityDetails">
```

Additionally, remove `@` from starting of `@<div`

Comment: @Cal, I have updated answer. Your variable was `Activity` but was using `activity`. Try it

Comment: That's great! thanks a lot matey! I've marked your answer as correct, if you're any good with JQuery then you might be able to help me with the final solution to this problem, so let me know :)

Comment: @Cal, I am good with jQuery, you can check my profile. Post a separate question and ping me

Comment: see this post :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977369/mvc-grid-vb-show-details-on-hover

Comment: For anyone looking at this post for reference, the second line is the one that worked for me, thanks again @Satpal